# Showing a Hilbert space operator to be zero under some conditions

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T:H\to H$ be a bounded linear operator satisfying $\left\langle T^{2}(x), x \right\rangle \geq 0$ and  $\left\langle Tx, x \right\rangle =0$ $\forall x \in H$.    Show that $T=0$.

I want to show  $\langle Tx, y \rangle =0$ for all $x, y \in H$.  But I haven't been able to do it.  Also I think that the adjoint operator can come into play. But I cannot manipulate the two conditions.

Thank you!

Comment: If $X$ is a complex space, then
$$
          \langle Tx,y\rangle = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}i^n\langle T(x+i^ny),x+i^n y\rangle = 0,\;\;\; x,y\in H.
$$ Are you assuming $X$ is a real space?

Answer (score 3):

Let  $x,y\in H$. Using $\langle Tu,u\rangle=0$ for any $u\in H$, we derive that 
$$0=\langle T(x+y),x+y\rangle=\langle Tx,y\rangle+\langle x,Ty\rangle$$
hence $T^*=-T$.

Using now $\langle T^2u,u\rangle=0$, we get that $\langle Tu,T^*u\rangle\geqslant 0$ hence $0\leqslant \lVert Tu\rVert^2\leqslant 0$ and $T=0$.

Comment: I have got the inequality.  But after using the parallelogram law I can't show that T is self adjoint.  I suppose that we want to show $||Tx-T^{*}x|| \leq 0$ which will give us that T is self adjoint.  Can you help me with that?

Comment: @user106849 I have added more detail.

Comment: But the left hand side has a 2 multiplied to what you are saying The parallelogram law is $||x+y||^{2}+||x-y||^{2}$=2(||x||^{2}+||y||^{2})

Comment: @user106849 You are right. I found an other way.

Comment: i didn't get the first equality

Comment: @user106849 I have edited again.

Comment: Why $\langle Tx,T^{*}x \rangle \leq o$??